# RapidMiner: Can I use a wildcard as an attribute value for training a decision tree model?

Tags: regex, csv, classification, decision-tree, rapidminer

I am working on a fairly simple *process* in RapidMiner 5.3.013, which reads a CSV file and uses it as a training set to train the decision tree classifier. The result of the process is the model. A second CSV is read and used as the unlabeled set. The model (calculated earlier) is *applied* to the unlabeled test set, in an effort to label it properly.

Each line of the CSVs contains a few attributes, for example:
15, 0, 1555, abc*15, label1

but some lines of the training set may be like this:
15, 0, *****, abc*15, label2
This is done because the third value may take various values, so the creator of the training set used a star as a wildcard in the place of the value.

**What I would like to do is let the decision tree know that the star there means "match anything", so that it does not literally only match a star.**

Notes:

1. the star in the 4th field (abc*15) should be matched literally and not as a wildcard.
2. if the 3rd field always contained stars, I could just not include it in the attributes, but that's not the case. Sometimes the 3rd field contains integer values, which should be matched literally.
3. I tried leaving the field blank, but it doesn't work

**So, is there a way to use regular expressions, or at least a simple wildcard while training the classifier or using the model?**

A different way to put it is: **Can I instruct the classifier to not use some of the attributes in some of the entries (lines in the CSV)?**

Thanks!

Comment: What I ended up doing was to modify the decision tree model creator's Java code. And it worked! And I used it in my Thesis :). I've been waiting until I get some free time to properly write an answer, but it won't happen anytime soon, thus this comment is all I'll do for now. If someone needs more details please ask, I'll be around.

Answer (score 1):

I would process the data so the missing value is valid in its own right and I would discretize the valid numbers to be in ranges.

In more detail, what I meant by missing is the situation where the value of an attribute is something like `*`. I would simply allow this to be one valid value that the attribute takes. For all the other values of this attribute, these are numerical so they need to be converted to a nominal value to be compatible with the now valid `*`.

It's fairly fiddly to do this and I haven't tried this but I would start with the operator `Declare Missing Value` to detect the `*` and make them missing. From there, I would use the operator `Discretize by Binning` to convert numbers into nominal values. Finally, I would use `Replace Missing Values` to change the missing values to a nominal value like `Missing`. You might ask why bother with the first Declare Missing step above? The reason is that it will allow the Discretizing operation to work because it will be working on numbers alone given that non-numbers are marked as missing.

The resulting example set then be passed to a model in the normal way. Obviously, the model has to be able to cope with nominal attributes (Decision trees does).

It occurred to me that some modelling operators are more tolerant of missing data. I think k-nearest-neighbours may be one. In this case, you could simply mark the missing ones as above and not bother with the discretizing step.

The whole area of missing data does need care because it's important to understand the source of missingness. If missing data is correlated with other attributes or with the label itself, handling it inappropriately can skew results.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you please add an example or a bit more explanation to help me understand the solution better?
<<<<line break> >>> Part1: I can pre-process the data (both training and test sets) but what do you mean by "missing value"? Maybe the wildcard in the training set?
<<<<line break> >>>
Part2: So instead of treating individual values as nominal, I could declare them as numeric and have the tree make ranges, right? That's not really addressing the issue though, as the wildcard should match any value, so range would be 0 to max.

Comment: My previous reply was a bit brief - I'll edit that directly so it's more standalone.